# Select a set of values from Array based on value

Tags: powershell

I am using following PowerShlell to get the list of available physical disk.

```
$disks=((Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true)|Select-Object PhysicalLocation)
```

The output of above code is as shown below

Integrated : Adapter 3 : Port 0 : Target 0 : LUN 7

Integrated : Adapter 3 : Port 0 : Target 0 : LUN 0

Integrated : Adapter 3 : Port 0 : Target 0 : LUN 5

Integrated : Adapter 3 : Port 0 : Target 0 : LUN 2

Integrated : Adapter 3 : Port 0 : Target 0 : LUN 6

Integrated : Adapter 3 : Port 0 : Target 0 : LUN 4

Integrated : Adapter 3 : Port 0 : Target 0 : LUN 1

Integrated : Adapter 3 : Port 0 : Target 0 : LUN 3

Integrated : Adapter 3 : Port 0 : Target 0 : LUN 8

However, form the collection I want to select a set of LUN e.g LUN from 5 to 8 to create a storage pool using

> New-StoragePool

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the expressions in parenthesis. You can try something like below. This regex will help you to get the desired result.

```
Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true | Foreach-Object -Process {
   $_.PhysicalLocation | Select-String -Pattern 'LUN.[5-8]'
}
```